# What is the difference between startDate and a filter on "published" in the Okta Events API?

Tags: okta, okta-api

I've written a .NET app using the Okta.Core.Client 0.2.9 SDK to pull events from our organization's syslog for import into another system. We've got it running every 5 minutes, pulling events published since the last event received in the previous run.

We're seeing delays on some events showing up. If I do a manual run at the top of the hour for the previous hour's data, it'll include more rows than the 5-minute runs. While trying to figure out why I remembered the `startDate` param, mutually-exclusive with the `filter` one I've been using.

The [docs](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/events.html#list-events) don't mention much about it - just that it "Specifies the timestamp to list events after". Does it work the same as `published gt "some-date"`? We're capturing data for chunks of time, so I needed to include a "less than" filter and ignored startDate. But the delayed events have me looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you facing delayed results using startDate or filter?

Yes published gt "some-date" and startDate work the same way. The following two API calls.

/api/v1/events?limit=100&startDate=2016-07-06T00:00:00.000Z

and

/api/v1/events?limit=100&filter=published gt "2016-07-06T00:00:00.000Z"

returns the same result. Since, they are mutually exclusive filter might come in handy in creating more specific queries including the other query parameters in your query using filter.

Comment: Thanks - we've been using `filter` as doing the 5-minute approach meant asking for "on or after time X, before time Y" so `startDate` wouldn't cut it. I guess however Okta processes and collates event logs means we'll need to wait at least an hour to make sure we have everything.